# Does registering an app at Stack Apps immediately make it publicly viewable?

Tags: support, stackapps

Does filling out the [registration form](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) at Stack Apps make information about the app publicly viewable or otherwise imply that the app is for public consumption?

Context: I am considering writing a small app that will essentially be for my personal use, and would like to register it to get a larger request quota. If, however, registering an app implies that it is or should be public in some sense, I will be happy to live with the anonymous quota.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, registration does not make anything about your app publicly viewable. Upon registration, the software gives you the keys and creates a dashboard page for your app with URL `http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/view/xxxx`. This page is not accessible to the public.

Also, the sidebar of registration page explains:

> Why Register?
>
> Because it's the neighborly thing to do. We like to know who is using our API, and how, so we can have the metrics we need to support your application and improve the API together.
>
> Once it's ready for public consumption, we'll help you promote your registered application here on Stack Apps.

Registering achieves the primary goal, stated in the first paragraph. If it turns out that your app will never be ready for public consumption... that would not be unusual. A lot of products are developed that never ship.

<sup>Disclaimer: I do not work for SE. The post summarizes my own observations of StackApps.</sup>